# Defining and generalizing a recursive function applied $n$ times

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

First of all, I am not a mathematician so forgive me for the errors.

I am dealing with a processing pipeline that applies a reduction function, $r(x)$, $n$ times at its core, where:

$$r(x) = \lceil x/2 \rceil$$

If I am applying this function $n = 3$ times then, the processing pipeline function $R_n(x)$ would be:

$$R_3(x) = r(r(r(x)))$$

How could I generalize this expression for an arbitrary $n$ number of times? I am looking for:

$$R_n(x) = ¿?$$

I know this must be very simple, but I just can not generalize it. I have search over recursive functions like the Fibonacci which gave me some clues but still can not generalize it. Thanks in advance community!

Comment: What is your goal? To obtain an explicit expression for $R_n(x)$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: Yes! thank you for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple:
$$R_n(x) = \lceil \frac{x}{2^n} \rceil$$
Applying $r$ will halve the value, so applying it $n$ times will divide by $2^n$. The repeated roundings upwards turn out not to matter, and can just be done once at the end.

Comment: Really appreciated man, upvoted. However I don't really see how the rounding upwards does not matter, is it distributive?

Comment: OK, tested, it really works! Thank you!

Comment: Those upward roundings get halved by any subsequent applications of $r$, so all together the roundings never add up to more than one in the final answer, and can then be handled by just a single rounding in $R_n$.